# How to run a wifi management program in android emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-wifi, android-wireless

I'm working on **a basic android wifi management program**, but I don't have a real device. So I have to run it on **android emulator**?

I have searched, and understand that **I can't work real wifi network**. But it's not important for now, I just want to test my program on emulator.

I want to ask that if I can add **virtual wifi networks** to my emulator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is about as close as you can get:

http://kmansoft.com/2010/07/27/debugging-wifi-in-the-emulator/

Strong suggestion: buy a small, cheap, no-contract handset.  T-Mobile and Virgin both offer them, you can buy them at Target, Best Buy, Radio Shack, etc (in the U.S., at least)

Comment: thanks, this is what I want. now I wonder that If I install android on a virtual machine (android on laptop), can I use wifi connection? I think it may be like an android phone?

Comment: I've never actually tried it ... but yes, I imagine something like this might indeed work:  http://quinxy.com/2011/03/12/running-android-2-2-in-vmware-in-less-than-5-minutes/  I *can* tell you with assurance that if you had a physical handset, you could connect it to your PC, or to your local WiFi LAN, without any problem.